# PHP Image Upload - Undefined fileToUpload

Tags: php, html, image, image-uploading

I have a admin page where admin will insert a new product in the form. I can't upload the image, getting undefined fileToUpload Error. I need to upload an image and stored the image name into a database.

Here's my code:

```
session_start();
include_once '../inc/config.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['insert'])) 
{
$cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['cname']);
$ccost = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ccost']);
$ctype = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ctype']);
$cimage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['cimage']);
$ccapa = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['ccapa']);
$cstatus = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['cstatus']);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
 if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
 echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
 $uploadOk = 0;
 }
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType 
!= "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}

if(mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO cars(car_name, car_type, image, rent_cost, capacity, status) VALUES
    ('".$cname."', '".$ctype."', '". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "', '".$ccost."', '".$ccapa."', '".$cstatus."')")){
        $success = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Successfully Inserted!</strong></div>";
    }else{
        $errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error inserting item.</div>";
    }
}
```

My HTML Code:

```html
<div id="insert" class="collapse">
    </br>
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Insert an Item</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Car Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="cname" type="text" placeholder="Enter car name.." class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Rent Cost</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="ccost" type="number" placeholder="Enter rent cost.." class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Car Type</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="ctype" type="text" placeholder="Enter car type.." class="form-control input-md" required="">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- File Button --> 
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Image File</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="filebutton" name="fileToUpload" class="input-file" type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Capacity</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="ccapa" type="number" placeholder="Enter car capacity.." class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Status</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="cstatus" class="form-control">
      <option value="Available">Available</option>
      <option value="Not Avaialble">Not Available</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="singlebutton" name="insert" class="btn btn-success">Insert</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

  </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag
2. Make sure that your server can accept POST and upload data that is
   large enough to accommodate the size of your files
3. Do a `print_r($_FILES)` after your form is submitted to see if
   `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` is defined

Comment: Done number 1 and 2. For number 3, I haven't submitted any data yet, its display the error

Comment: Your script shouldn't even be getting to the block where the file upload is getting processed unless isset($_POST['insert']) is true. Can you reply reply with the exact PHP error that you're seeing?  Also consider putting a print_r($_REQUEST) at the top of your script to monitor what inputs your script is getting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` after `action=""` in you form tag. Or else the data sent to the server won't be identified.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who answered my questions. I already fixed my issues.

- For undefined variables, I just need to put it inside of isset($_POST(['insert']).
- For the PHP Upload Script, I just need to remove: 
  `$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
  echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
  $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
  echo "File is not an image.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  }`
- And yes, enctype="multipart/form-data" is required in  tag in order to post the image/media to the server.

and that fixed it.